# Rendering animation stops at night

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, smoke-simulation

I have this animation that also includes a fire/smoke simulation. I first rendered that animation at night (with CPU rendering). Although it lasted ages every went ok. But now I have started rendering this animation with GPU (I use Blender 2.77 RC) the render stops every night. And apparently for some reason Blender quits.

I have a couple of question related to this issue:

1) what can be the reason for this ... the rendering stopping every night ? The render runs on a Windows/NVIDIA machine. Is this because of some "power settings" ? It is weird that the render only stops at night since during the day there also are periods that the windows machine is rendering and I am not working at the computer. By the way, during the day the monitor is shared with a MAC machine and I shut down the MAC at the end of the day

2) If I restart the render can I start it at the first frame not rendered yet (it involves a fire simulation) ?

3) I notice that when Blender has quitted also the bake of my fire simulation has gone ?? Why is this ? And can I simply rebake and start the render at the first frame not rendered yet ?

Comment: 1. Do you, perhaps, have two fire/smoke emitters in one domain that intersect?

I had a problem like this once where two flames went through each other and the emitters inside the domain intersected, that crashed the render on that specific frame.

2. yes you can, however if its a specific frame that wont render, thats going to need to be skipped

3. The bake shouldnt disappear, did you click on bake or just ALT+A?

Comment: @AdamTM I have only one smoke emitter. I really did bake (not just ALT+A)

Comment: As for 2 you can uncheck *Overwrite* in Render Output settings, it will make Blender check if current rendered frame already exists (or you can set frame range of animation). As for 3, the baked sim should be there even if program is reopened and smoke should be visible in viewport. Check if files of sim exist, check settings of smoke cache and make sure not to free the bake. I don't think I faced similar cache dissappearing.

Comment: I guess I did free the bake. What happens exactly when you free the bake ?

Comment: @OldMan do you figured out what happened? I got a similar situation.